# Soulcalibur VI is suspiciously slow for my GPU after I switch to Windows 11

Tags: performance, gpu, windows-11

I played Soulcalibur VI. It plays well. Then I increase the resolution to 3840 2160. It's slow. But for a while, I like it slow.

Then I upgrade to windows 11. It's still slow. I change resolution to 1920 1080 again. It's still slow.

I wonder if there is a way to check for frame rate in windows 11?

Anyway my GPU is [Radeon RX 5700 XT](https://www.videocardbenchmark.net/gpu.php?gpu=Radeon%20RX%205700%20XT&id=4111)

That is 4 times more powerful than RX460 I used in another computer. And the other computer is doing fine running Soulcalibur VI

Someone says that my computer may have used GPU in CPU rather than the proper GPU.

I have no idea how to test it.

Comment: Is your monitor actually connected to the RX 5700 rather than the motherboard ports? Is this a laptop or a desktop?

Comment: desktop. After it reached 3840 2160 I do not think that's the problem. Let me check again. The TV refresh rate is the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

I turned off v-sync

It went faster. However, sometimes there is a horizontal glitch.

Then I look at what v sync is all about. It's for monitor with low refresh rate. Turns out my monitor has adjustable refresh rate.

I turned it to 60 frame per second. It got even faster.

Then I thought, what the hell.

I set it to 3840 2160

Still running fast.

So the monitor refresh rate must be 60 frame per second.